# Azure pipeline is failing when we use ng serve or npm run start

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment

I am trying to build a azure pipeline for a nodejs project. While deploying the application via release pipeline to  azure web app, if I use "npx serve -s" it is working but if I use "npm run start"/"node server.js"/"ng serve" it is not working. Can someone explain what is the issue?

Comment: could you share the logs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605219/difference-between-npx-and-npm

Answer (score 0):

I think when you start with your project, it will like run something like below in pipline.

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: deploy
  inputs: 
   azureSubscription: 'yoursubscription'
   appType: webAppLinux
   webappName: 'angularproj'
   deployToSlotOrASE: true
   ResourceGroupName: mygroup
   packageForLinux: dist/myangularapp

   StartupCommand: 'npx serve -s'
```

For more details, you can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264905/not-able-to-deploy-nodejs-with-angular-app-into-azure-web-app-using-azure-devops/60323842#60323842).